# What is a non-linear space of connections

Tags: gauge-theory, representation-theory, wilson-loop

In the book "Loops Knots Gauge Theory and Quantum Gravity" when trying to define a loop representation, one needs to integrate over the space of connections (modulo Gauge transformations). There, they say this space is non-linear and inf-dim. What does it mean for a space to be non-linear?

(The space of 1 forms is a vector-space no?)

Comment: Methinks it means that the space of solutions to classical yang mills eom is not a vector space, now that I think about it. Need confirmation though. (They claim that the Klein gordon space is linear, which fits my def)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be a principal fibre bundle and $\mathrm{Con}(\pi)$ the bundle of smooth principal connections over $\pi$. This can actually be realized as an *affine* bundle over $M$ whose total space is $J^1(\pi)/G$, where $G$ is the structure group. The corresponding vector bundle is $\mathrm{Ad}(\pi)\otimes\Lambda^1(M)$, where $\mathrm{Ad}(\pi)$ is the vector bundle associated to $\pi$ through the adjoint representation of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$.

More generally if $\pi:N\rightarrow M$ is a fibered manifold, then the space of all smooth connections on $\pi$ can be identified with $\Gamma(\pi^1_0)$, where $\pi^1_0:J^1(\pi)\rightarrow N$ is the first affine jet bundle of $\pi$. This is again an affine bundle (although over $N$ rather than $M$). The corresponding vector bundle is $V(\pi)\otimes_N\Lambda^1(M)$, where the tensor product is taken over $N$, and $V(\pi)$ is the vertical tangent bundle of $\pi:N\rightarrow M$.

In somewhat more familiar terms, connections of a given type (i.e. smooth sections of the corresponding bundles) always form an affine space. Affine spaces are "almost linear", but are nonetheless not vector spaces. Arbitrary linear combinations of connections are not themselves connections.

Comment: Whats $J^1(\pi)?$ EDIT: A quick wikipedia article revealed it. I need to read up a lot of things, so I cannot accept your answer yet. But thanks.

Comment: I unfortunately only understand the last part, which is convincing. Can you recommend any sources (online available) to read up concisely stuff about connection (bundles). I have not seen that before.

Comment: @Confuse-ray30 Check out "Natural Operations in Differential Geometry" by Kolár, Michor and Slovák. It's available freely (and legally!) online. Although I'm afraid it's not very concise.